# preg_match behaviour unexpected on string \x00\x01

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a loop which sometimes contains this data:
`b"\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x1D›¿\x04\x04›?‹„\x12¿Ã’\x11?"`

When I put this into regex101, I can match items using the following regex:
`/((\\x[\d]{2}){4,}.*)/gm`

See example: https://regex101.com/r/cMyKVg/1/

When I put this in my php script it's like this:

```
preg_match( '/(x)/m', $value, $matches )
```

`$value` has the value of the string above.

I have no matches using this code.
I've also tried matching it literally:

```
preg_match( '/((\\x[\d]{2}){4,}.*)/m', 'b"\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x1D›¿\x04\x04›?‹„\x12¿Ã’\x11?"', $matches ),
```

But it doesn't match anything.

I don't want this value in my database, therefore I want to use a regex to skip values like this.

Can someone please explain this behaviour to me and maybe help to fix it?

**EDIT:**
I have a feeling that the string I used is not actually what is going in the `preg_match`, it is the value I get with a `var_dump` but it seems like `preg_match` gets a different value. I accidentally typed an error and then I got this message:

```
ErrorException  : preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 3

  at /Users/used/Sites/project/app/Console/Commands/ExtractLibraryFileMetaData.php:204
    200|            dd(
    201|                $value,
    202|                \gettype($value),
    203|                $regex = '/(\\)/',
  > 204|                preg_match( $regex, $value, $matches ),
    205|                $matches
    206|            );
    207|        }
    208|        if ( preg_match( '/((\\x[\d]{2}){4,}.*)/m', $value ) ) {

  Exception trace:

  1   preg_match("/(\)/", "\\\\\\\\\\X���?���Ò?")
```

I have no idea what causes this. It's still the same value but it's displayed differently...

Comment: I think your main issue is that the input is a binary string, not a text string. i.e. `\x00` refers to the NUL byte (U+0000) and not the text `"\x00"`.

Comment: Are you sure you shared the exact data you have into the question? `'/(x)/m'` does not make sense against `'b"\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x1D›¿\x04\x04›?‹„\x12¿Ã’\x11?"'`

Comment: you need more `\ ` -> https://3v4l.org/US9Th

Comment: This reeks of XY problem to me...

Answer (score 0):

The hexadecimal characters aren't treated as strings, the actual output of the string is probably:

```
b"X›¿›?‹„¿Ã’?"
```

You could then match using **hexadecimal range**:

```
// I double-quoted the string
$str = "b\"\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x1D›¿\x04\x04›?‹„\x12¿Ã’\x11?\"";

// Matches characters from char code 0 to 31
preg_match_all('/([\x00-\x1F])/', $str, $m);
```

Output:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($m[0], true) . '</pre>';

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [12] => 
    [13] => 
    [14] => 
    [15] => 
    [16] => 
)
*/
```

Replace:

```
echo preg_replace('/([\x00-\x1F])/', '', $str);

// b"X›¿›?‹„¿Ã’?"
```

Comment: This is not working for me for some reason. Please see my edit. I think it has something to do with that.

Comment: @TheatreOfSouls I updated my answer, tell me if it solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems for whatever reason that preg_match in PHP needs three backward-slashes for escaping the \x correctly. I tested with this regex `preg_match('/((?:\\\x[\d]{2}){4,}.*)/m', $str, $matches)` and it worked.

You can find a live demo over here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4aecc4bf25ec82a98c8fbaee32b34693f3316f64

Comment: Not "whatever reason" - It's due to syntax of single quoted string.

Comment: This is not working for me for some reason. Please see my edit. I think it has something to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at regex101 [code generator](https://regex101.com/r/cMyKVg/1/codegen?language=php) at the bottom left under 'Tools'. You'll see some changes are made to both your regex and input string which is related to backslashes.

You can follow that approach or use a [nowdoc](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) like below:

```
preg_match(<<< 'RE'
/(?:\\x\d{2}){4,}.*/
RE
,$str, $matches);
```

See PHP [live demo here](https://3v4l.org/RoZkZ)

Comment: This is not working for me for some reason. Please see my edit. I think it has something to do with that.